# Changing multiple labels for levels in a dataframe

Tags: r, label, levels

Just started learning R a couple weeks ago, and getting the hang of it.

I have a df that has many different columns which are factors with 2 levels (0,1)
I wish to change the labels for the levels for all the columns that are factors.

I use the following code which executes but does **not** change the actual labels.

```
levels(df[18:34]) <- c("No", "Yes")
```

On suggestions of others I tried

```
df[18:34] <- lapply(df[18:34], factor, levels = c("No", "Yes"))
```

This code executed but converted the factor levels to NA

Comment: Take a look at `?lapply` - `lapply(df[18:34], function(x) levels(x) <- c("No","Yes") )` I think. You need to do it column-by-column.

Comment: Can you provide data to see how it is ? It is important to make the example reproducible.

Comment: okay thanks :), didnot know

Comment: Probable duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229294/how-to-make-the-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-data-frame-consistent-across-all-columns

Comment: Tried the lapply and the post by @thelatemail - None of those appear to work.

Comment: @user9938116 - did you save over the top of the original `df`? `df[18:34] <- lapply(...` for example.

Comment: I did indeed. The code executes but converts everything to an "NA". Here is the code I applied

'df[18:34] <- lapply(df[15:16], factor, levels <- c("No", "Yes"))'